# dynamic loading across multiple namespaces

Tags: c++, dlopen, dlsym

I am totally new to `dlsym` and I just reviewed [C++ dlopen mini HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/C++-dlopen.pdf)  .So please correct me if I am getting the concept and approaches wrong:

I am planning to write an application that takes `shared library` names as argument:

> ./my_app    libXYZ.so

Different input libraries use their own `namespaces` for declaring functions that happen to have similar signatures:

**libXXX.so:**

```
namespace X {
namespace Y {
namespace Z{

 ret_t func(arg_r);

}}}
```

**libABC.so:**

```
namespace A {
namespace B {
namespace C{

 ret_t func(arg_r);

}}}
```

- As you can see the function signatures are same.
- Just to be clear, although the libraries are in C++, I am only
  talking about calling some `C functions` in the library, not C++ member methods.
- The same `my_app` should be able to call `func()` without any other
  argument hints.

Naturally, every library contains a different mangled C++ symbol and I cannot create a single `extern "C"` clause that works for all(for example):

- $^%X^&Y&^&Zfunc&^arg*&*
- $#$A#$B&^&C&^func*&*arg^&*^&

The only way that comes in my mind is to get a list of library symbols, search for `func` sub-string (which is nasty and error prone) and formulate a `extern "C"` clause using macros. 
Can you please suggest a better solution?

Comment: Can't you have all shared objects exporting the same symbol (s)? When producing a plugin this is the usual approach...

Comment: @marom are you suggesting what Raydel is suggesting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't load a function without specify its namespace( unless in global namespace).

The namespace is part of the name of the function([since its declared in that scope](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)). In order to use it, you will have to use the [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) keyword or the fullname of the function (E.g **namespace::some_function**).

However, if what you want is get an uniform way to call such functions, you could create a common interface to all your libraries.

```
namespace A {
namespace B {
namespace C{

 ret_t func(arg_r);

}}}

extern "C" {
    ret_t call_func(arg_r)
    {
         return A::B::C::func(arg_r);
    }
}
```

and the same thing for the other library. So, in the client code of your library you only call `call_func(arg_r)`.

Comment: Although it works, I am looking for a way not to touch the library. As they are not my development tasks. I will also look for a way to iterate through the symbols programmatically. If I found a way, I will update.

Comment: I think, you´re overthinking the problem. The libraries are not your development task, but are making your work more complex.  If you work in a team, try first to talk to the library´s developer/s, at the end, is their task. On the other hand, you´re dealing with a design problem, if the libraries are intended to be some sort of plugin system, they have to implement a common interface. Suppose you find the solution you´re looking for, ¿Would implement you the solution for every library, whatever the namespaces names?

Comment: You are very right on making the work even more complex. It is not a plugin I am developing. I am trying to test those libraries, sort of a certification.  so.. you can tell what is the relationship between me and those who developed the libraries ;)

Comment: Yes, I understand. If I were you, one of my test results would say something like this: "the libraries has not a common interface". You have already enough elements to defend that result. The libraries are designed in a way, that makes developers write the client code in a non practical way.  So, to me, the libraries have failed the tests.